# How to send each item of response in Java Method (karate framework)?

Tags: karate

I have to send to my Java method each item in reponse, I have to do smth like this :
    response from GET/cars request

```
 * def wheels = response[*].wheels
    * def JavaM = Java.Type('foo.bar.JavaMethods')
    * def modifiedWheels = JavaM.modifyWheels(wheels)
```

I've read about call-table.feature but I can't figure out if I have to send each wheel one by one in my java method or if I have to send an array of wheels and my Java method should treat this array? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A JSON array becomes a Java `List`.

A JSON object becomes a `Map<String, Object>`.

Refer to this section in the doc: https://github.com/intuit/karate#calling-java, there is even an example [`cats-java.feature`](https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-demo/src/test/java/demo/java/cats-java.feature)